# Facebook Scraper Shows Tiny Little Icon Image instead of Large Banner Image

Tags: facebook, image

I have read many similar posts here and tried the following but no luck:

1. Replaced `og:image` with larger image banner (larger than Facebook's required standard)
2. Commented out the `<img>` tag of that pencil icon image, yet Facebook debugger still showing that small tiny little icon. When I view source from browser, confirmed that pencil icon has been commented. **(NOTE: I've put back the pencil icon image for editing convenience.)**
3. Renamed large image file and update `og:image`.
4. Specified `og:url` of the current page.

All the above not working at all. Can somebody please help? Here is my URL: http://tringo-medical.blogspot.my/. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, sorry for the impatience -- we just have to wait for Facebook to clear the cache. For my case, I had been waited for **almost a week** for them to get it cleared, which wasn't in 24 hours as what others claimed. But Facebook shouldn't defeat their own rules either by choosing tiny icon image as the post image. So the solution is to **"wait"**.